# macro for class accessors

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a macro, which writes accesors for a class automatically for all slots. I came up with this

```
(defmacro defacc (class)
  (loop for name in (mapcar #'slot-definition-name
                            (class-slots (class-of (make-instance `,class))))
       do
       `(defun ,name (,class)
          (slot-value ,class ',name))))
```

But it does not define any function( Without loop, it works for single function and single slot name. I don't get where s the problem. I also tried `(class-of (make-instance 'class))` and `(class-of ',class)`. Still no function appears.

P.S. I did not forget to actually write this macro with my classes.

Comment: A `do`-clause in `LOOP` discards the results. You would have to collect all the definitions into a `PROGN` form that you return from the macro. However, for the actual goal, I'd prefer to define the class with a macro that expands into `DEFCLASS` with the appropriate accessors/readers.

Comment: I removed do and put progn in there
Doesn't seem to work tho(

Comment: You want to replace DO with something which collects. Like COLLECT.

Comment: Ok, it almost works. But it collects all the definitions into brackets (). WhIch then does not allow to define it. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: see the comment about PROGN

Comment: Yes, but I added progn as well. It does the same thing. I think, since this is the single expression in progn, it still returns it

Comment: Note that, as it stands, your macro has a syntax error (comma outside a backquote): it would be good to fix that, at least.

Comment: Oh, it's a mistake in my post, thx.

Comment: You need to think about what code you want to generate. This is the first step: which code do you want to generate. Then write a macro which actually does that. Not the other way. Expand an example macro form to see if your macro works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the class definitions you want to add automatic slot-readers for then the easy way to do this is by using a customised `defclass` macro, for instance this:

```
(defmacro defclass/auto-reader (class supers
                                      slot-definitions
                                      &rest class-options)
  ;; This is exactly like DEFCLASS, except it will automagically add a
  ;; reader method for each slot, named after the slot.
  `(defclass ,class ,supers
     ,(mapcar #'(lambda (slot-definition)
                  ;; Rewrite the slot definitions as needed
                  (etypecase slot-definition
                    ;; A slot definition can either be ...
                    (symbol
                     ;; ... a symbol naming the slot, in which case we
                     ;; need to create a listy slot definition with a
                     ;; reader specified ...
                     `(,slot-definition :reader ,slot-definition))
                    (list
                     ;; ... or a list, whose first element is the name
                     ;; of the slot and whose remaining elements
                     ;; define various options.  In this case we just
                     ;; append the specification of the reader method
                     ;; we need to the list (this might be slightly
                     ;; fragile: I don't know what happens if you end
                     ;; up with something like
                     ;;  (x ... :reader x ... :reader x)
                     ;; but this is not likely a problem in practice).
                     (append slot-definition 
                             `(:reader ,(first slot-definition))))))
              slots)
     ,@class-options))
```

This will automatically define readers, and will also make those readers work robustly (for instance they will work if you have two classes which define the same slot name).

---

Note that it's not clear to me that a separate `defacc` macro can work.  In particular consider trying to compile a file containing something like this:

```
(defclass foo (...)
  (s1 s2 ...))
...
(defacc foo ...)
```

Here `defacc` needs to be able to find out `foo`'s slots *at compile time*, and I am fairly sure that it can't reliably do this: the [spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defcla.htm) tells you that `defclass` needs to make some information about the class available at compile-time (for instance that it is a class) but I am not at all sure it needs to make things like slot definitions available. However, the MOP is outside the specification in any case and it may be that MOPpy implementations (all of them I guess) do make this information available.

Comment: Nice. Next thing was to add functions there so `setf` could work with those accessors too. I ll try this myself, I think

Comment: Can you explain the code a little bit? Started lisping like 2 months ago.

Comment: for example, why would someone name a slot of a class with a ... list?
Isn't it always a symbol?

Comment: I've added a bunch of comments to the definition.

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 5):

**defining individual functions**

Let's say you have two forms defining functions `foo` and `bar`.

```
CL-USER 68 > (defun foo (baz) baz)
FOO

CL-USER 69 > (defun bar (baz) baz)
BAR
```

**defining more functions in one Lisp form**

Now you want to use these two forms in one Lisp form. They typical way is to use an operator, which provides a body of forms.

`progn` is such an operator. Its subforms will be executed one by one and the last results are returned.

```
CL-USER 70 > (progn
               (defun foo (baz) baz)
               (defun bar (baz) baz))
BAR
```

**generating a PROGN form**

Now imagine that you have Lisp code as data, here as a list of Lisp forms.

```
CL-USER 71 > '((defun foo (baz) baz)
               (defun bar (baz) baz))
((DEFUN FOO (BAZ) BAZ)
 (DEFUN BAR (BAZ) BAZ))
```

To create a valid `progn` form, you just need to cons `progn` to the front of the list:

```
CL-USER 72 > (cons 'progn
                   '((defun foo (baz) baz)
                     (defun bar (baz) baz)))
(PROGN
 (DEFUN FOO (BAZ) BAZ)
 (DEFUN BAR (BAZ) BAZ))
```

**a macro generating a PROGN form**

That's what the macro needs to generate: a valid `progn` form.

Example for a macro generating a `progn` form:

```
CL-USER 74 > (defmacro baz (sym)
               (cons 'progn
                     `((defun foo (,sym) ,sym)
                       (defun bar (,sym) ,sym))))
BAZ

CL-USER 75 > (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(baz fourtytwo)))

(PROGN
  (DEFUN FOO (FOURTYTWO) FOURTYTWO)
  (DEFUN BAR (FOURTYTWO) FOURTYTWO))
```

Answer (score 4):

`Defclass` already has the slot options to define accessors, readers, and writers:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((bar :accessor foo-bar)))
```

This defines, along with the class, a method `foo-bar` specialized on `foo` that returns the value of the `bar` slot, as well as a method `setf foo-bar` to write to that slot.  There is also a `:reader` and a `:writer` option to define them separately.

A lot of people have written their own wrappers around `defclass` to make this even more convenient (e. g. automatically using a naming convention).  However, the drawback is that the locally used wrapper is most likely not familiar to others, and the added cognitive load is often not seen as worth the minor convenience improvement.